# Simple use of facebook graph with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I want to get the user content after he sign in with the login button

therefore I need to convert this code from php to rails 3

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
$cookie['access_token']));
```

I don't want to use any gem like httparty.

I tried this code with no success

```
uri = URI.parse(URI.encode('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + fbhash['access_token']))
    require 'net/http'
    content = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    content = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(content)
```

fbhash['access_token'] contain the right access_token for the user

the error message I get is

```
end of file reached
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using open-uri

```
content = open(URI.encode('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + fbhash['access_token']))
content = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(content)
```

works great